# Converting dictionary to table for Output in Orangewidget

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, widget, orange

is there a simple way to convert a dictionary of Objects into a Table which is needed to transport Data from one Widget to another?

I have a dictionary of measuringpoints with Lists of values and want to transport them form my own Widget to a 'Data Table Widget'.

I've tryed to convert the dictionary into a pandas Dataframe and after this convert the dataframe into a Table by using the following code [Converting Pandas DataFrame to Orange Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859770/2721590). 
I can execute the code in PyCharm without errors but when I start it in Orange the converting of the dataframe fails and stops without sending any errors.

Or is there maby a better way to create Output Data from dictionaries or dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

The code in your linked question appears to be for Orange 2, whereas Orange 3 is the current version. A [recent issue](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/2932) indicates this might be the code you can use to convert a pandas data frame into Orange data table:

```
from Orange.data.pandas_compat import table_from_frame

table = table_from_frame(df)
```